# Reference for Learning about Nuclear Operators on Banach Spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

What would be a nice references for learning about nuclear operators on Banach spaces?

I can't give more details of what I'm looking for since I know nothing about those operators.

I don't care about pre-requisites for I'll have to learn about it anyway for my thesis.

Thanks.

Comment: A classic reference is Gel'fand and Vilenkin's Generalized Functions, Vol. 4, chapter 1. Reed and Simon's functional analysis book treats trace-class operators (which I think are the same thing as nuclear operators, except in the special setting of a Hilbert space).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them =)